# Atiyah-Macdonald, Chapter 3, Exercise 18. Why is $B_q$ a local ring of $B_p$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization

This question is on the hint that the book gives to finish the exercise.

> Namely, if $f: A \rightarrow B$ a homomorphism of rings, $q$ a prime ideal of $B$ and $p = q^c$, then $B_q$ is a local ring of $B_p$.

I can't make sense out of this statement...  Is that saying the image of $q$ of in $B_p$ a prime ideal of $p$ through the map $b \mapsto \frac{b}{1}$? But this map is not always injective.  But otherwise how do we understand $B_q$ as a localization of $B_p$ over some prime ideal? I don't understand...

Can someone give an explicit explanation of this statement?

Comment: I don't understand, if you are localizing at ideals they sould be prime, and if $q$ is a prime ideal, then $q^c$ is not always prime...
Are you sure he doesn't mean localise at (the multiplicatively closed set) $\{1,q,q^2,q^3,\cdots\}$

Comment: The property has nothing to do with flatness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what's confusing is first what $B_\mathfrak{p}$ is.

$B_\mathfrak{p}$ is the localization of $B$ at $\mathfrak{p}$, considered as an $A$-module via the morphism $f\colon A \to B$, i.e., $B_\mathfrak{p} \cong B \otimes_A A_\mathfrak{p}$, and in particular it is defined by localizing with respect to the multiplicative set $\{f(a) \mid a \in A \setminus \mathfrak{p}\}$ (it is multiplicative since $f$ is a ring homomorphism).

Then, by "$B_\mathfrak{q}$ is a local ring of $B_\mathfrak{p}$" is that $B_\mathfrak{q}$ is obtained by further localizing with respect to a prime ideal in $B$, and we can see this by the fact that $\{f(a) \mid a \in A \setminus \mathfrak{p}\} \subseteq \{b \mid b \in B \setminus \mathfrak{q}\}$.

One thing to mention is that $B_\mathfrak{p}$ is not necessarily a local ring: if you trust Exercise $3.21$, $\operatorname{Spec} B_\mathfrak{p}$ corresponds to the preimage of primes contained in $\mathfrak{p}$ under the map $f^*\colon \operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A$, and $\operatorname{Spec} B_\mathfrak{p}$ can be large in general.

Now the conclusion of the problem follows by property (*iii*) in Exercise 3.16.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  One followup question: So if a ring $A$ got localized twice over two multiplicative sets $S \subset T$, is $T^{-1}A$ the same as $S^{-1}A$ localized at the image of $T$ inside $S^{-1}A$?  It gets confusing with modules though, since for modules the ring changes after localization too.

Comment: Yes, this is Exercise 3.3 in Atiyah-Macdonald, at least for rings. Module-wise I'm not exactly sure which ring you're considering your module to be over, but in your situation they should be the same over $S^{-1}A$ at least; see Exercise 3.8.

Comment: This is really helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: One thing confuses me still...  You say that $B_q$ is obtained by further localize $B_p$, and you consider $B_p$ the same as $B$ localized at the image of of $B-f(A-p)$.  They are isomorphic, but not in the sense of ring, it's in the sense of $A_p$-module, according to Ex 3.4.  How do we connect this to the ring structure?

Comment: Off the top of my head, the only way to check this is to write out the module isomorphism explicitly and check it is in fact also a ring map. Usually this isn't difficult but I don't know if there is some "abstract nonsense" way to see this without some work.

Comment: I guess you are right, there is no way around it.  I will try that :)

Comment: It's also very confusing to me. $B_\mathfrak{p}$ is an $A$-module, but not a ring, right? But you said $B_\mathfrak{p}$ is "not necessarily a local ring".